# 301 redirects - problems with dashes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For some unknown reason some of my 301 redirects work fine and some don't I cannot for the life of me work out why.

These ones are fine:

```
# Permanent URL redirect
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /uk http://www.mysite.co.uk
Redirect 301 /uk/about-us http://www.mysite.co.uk/about-us/
Redirect 301 /uk/privacy-policy http://www.mysite.co.uk/privacy-policy/
Redirect 301 /uk/withdrawal http://www.mysite.co.uk/withdrawal-consent/
Redirect 301 /uk/promotions http://www.mysite.co.uk/promotions/
```

These ones do not work:

```
Redirect 301 /uk/feedback-enquiries http://www.mysite.co.uk/feedback/
Redirect 301 /uk/success-stories http://www.mysite.co.uk/testimonials/
```

and I get these 2 URLs returned as 404s:

```
http://www.mysite.co.uk/feedback-enquiries
http://www.mysite.co.uk/success-stories
```

It's as if there's an issue with the hyphens/dashes..but only when the page name has actually changed and only when the original pages uses a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code(Replace each Url with concerning main/redirect url) - -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uk/feedback-enquiries$
RewriteRule .* http://www.mysite.co.uk/feedback/ [L,R=301]
```

All your url should work by this pattern, Let me know if still you face any issue.

Comment: Can you kindly explain why that would be the case?  I can't think of any reason, frankly, so, I doubt it'll do anything differently.